# Using firebase to get multiple individual values given an array of keys

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, promise

I'm trying to access multiple individual keys in Firebase. I'm using a promise-based function and a `for` loop to iterate over the given keys.

Here's the code:

```
function getFirebaseData(key_arr)
{
   var ref_obj,
       data_obj = {}; 
   return new Promise(function(resolve)
   {
       for(var i = 0; i < key_arr.length; i++)
       {
           key_str = key_arr[i];
           ref_obj = firebase.database().ref('path/'+key_str);
           ref_obj.on('value', function(snapshot) 
           {
               data_obj[key_str] = snapshot.val();
           });
        }
        resolve(data_obj);
   });
}
```

And then I run this as follows:

```
var key_arr = ['first_key', 'second_key', 'third_key'];
getFirebaseData(key_arr).then(function(result){console.log(result);});
```

The problem is that the result I get isn't all three keys; I only get one. I guess this is because the code inside the `for` loop is asynchronous, so `resolve` only gives me the first key.

How can I rewrite this in such a way that I can wait for the `for` loop to complete and return the full result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The previous answer is solid, except the promise returned resolves to an array of `data_obj`

So, what you need to do is to change each iteration of the loop to a promise, then wait for all promises to resolve using `Promise.all`

Here is how you would do it using ES2015 - as you're using Promises, ES2015 isn't such a stretch anyway

```
function getFirebaseData(key_arr) {
    return Promise.all(key_arr.map(key_str =>
        new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
            firebase.database().ref('path/'+key_str).once('value', snapshot => 
                resolve ([key_str, snapshot.val()])
            )
        )
    )).then(results =>
        results.reduce((result, [key, value]) => {
            result[key] = value;
            return result;
        }, {})
    );
}
```

which transpiles to old school ES5 as:

```
function getFirebaseData(key_arr) {
    return Promise.all(key_arr.map(function (key_str) {
        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
            return firebase.database().ref('path/' + key_str).once('value', function (snapshot) {
                return resolve([key_str, snapshot.val()]);
            });
        });
    })).then(function (results) {
        return results.reduce(function (result, item) {
            var key = item[0],
                value = item[1];
            result[key] = value;
            return result;
        }, {});
    });
}
```

Each individual promise now resolves to an array, basically `[key, value]`

the .then after Promise.all combines all those results to a single object, like: `{ key1: value1, key2: value2,` ...

> The code above uses `.once('value'` rather than `.on('value'` - as pointed out in the comments, using `.on` would leave the listener attached. As Promises can only be resolved ONCE, then it makes sense to use `.once`

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to put this together

Comment: `on()` leaves the listener attached.  Shouldn't `once()` be used here?

Comment: None. Shorthand arrow functions transpile that way because that's what they do. The return is redundant

Answer (score 1):

```
function getFirebaseData(key_arr)
{
   var ref_obj,
       data_obj = {},
       promises = [];

   for(var i = 0; i < key_arr.length; i++)
   {
       key_str = key_arr[i];
       promises.push(
           new Promise(function(resolve)
           {
               ref_obj = firebase.database().ref('path/'+key_str);
               ref_obj.on('value', function(snapshot) 
               {
                   data_obj[key_str] = snapshot.val();
               });
               resolve(data_obj);
           })
       )
   }

   return Promise.all(promises);
}
```

Minimal code change can be this. Basically, instead for return promise right away. create promises array and resolve it by `Promise.all`.

Comment: Thanks for this. Will see if I can tweak this some.

Answer (score 0):

This minor variation on Jaromanda's well-crafted answer makes use of the [key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key) property of a DataSnapshot (all credit to him for the design):

```
function getFirebaseData(key_arr) {
  return Promise.all(key_arr.map(key_str =>
    firebase.database().ref('path/'+key_str).once('value'))
  ).then(snapshots =>
    snapshots.reduce((result, snap) => {
      result[snap.key] = snap.val();
      return result;
    }, [])
  );
}
```